# Java user validation error

Tags: java, validation

Hello all I am trying to validate a set of inputs from a user, where it does not accept blanks, letter, letter with numbers, and numbers out of the range 0=100.

It goes fine except but when I input greater than 100, for example 150, it will catch and tell you to try again but when a letter is typed on the second prompt, it fails. And it'll only fail if the sequence of input is int is greater than 100 is input and the second input is a letter. I have a feeling it is the logic but I cant figure out exactly on which part.

It errors right on the line when arrayInt is declared (3rd set of while loop from validateUserInput method)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Ask for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //declare an array with index of 5
    int array[] = new int[5];

    //loop to prompt user to input 5 test scores, each of which are stored in array
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter score " + (i+1) + ": ");
        //array[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        String arrayInput = input.nextLine();
        arrayInput = validateUserInput (arrayInput);
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayInput);
    } 
    //call method to display test scores
    displayTestScores(array, array);
    //exit out
    System.out.println("Press any key to exit...");
    input.nextLine();
    System.exit(0);
}

//validate user input
public static String validateUserInput ( String arrayInput){
    //variable to itirate through the string
    int counter = 0;
    //variable to index
    int arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();

    //assign scanner for user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //loop to check if blank
    while (arrayInputLength == 0){
        System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
        arrayInput = input.nextLine();
        arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();
    }

    //loop to check if user inputs numbers mixed with letters, iterate using counter
    while (arrayInputLength > counter){
        if (!Character.isDigit(arrayInput.charAt(counter))){
            System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
            arrayInput = input.nextLine();
            arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();
            counter = 0;
        }
        else{
            counter ++;
        }
        while (arrayInputLength == 0){
            System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
            arrayInput = input.nextLine();
            arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();
        }  
    }

    //loop to check while there is something inputted, make sure only between 0 and 100
    while (arrayInputLength > 0 ){
        int arrayInt = Integer.parseInt (arrayInput);
        if (arrayInt > 0 && arrayInt <= 100){
            return arrayInput;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
            arrayInput = input.nextLine();
            arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();
        }
        while (arrayInputLength == 0 ){
            System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
            arrayInput = input.nextLine();
            arrayInputLength = arrayInput.length();
        }
    }
    return arrayInput;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`validateUserInput` has too much responsibility (and duplicate code).  It's trying to validate the user input and also get new input.  But that new input might not be valid either (which is causing the error in your question).

Separate getting user input from validating the input.  Consider changing

```
public static String validateUserInput ( String arrayInput)
```

to

```
public static boolean isValidInput(String arrayInput)
```

It **only** checks to see if the input is valid.  It does not prompt the user for new input.

Then within the `main` for loop, keep prompting the user for input until it is valid.

```
for(...) {
    ....
    while (!isValidInput(arrayInput)) {
        System.out.println("that is not an integer X such that: 0 <= x <= 100, try again");
        arrayInput = input.nextLine();
    }
    ....
}
```